# Error(s) during simple pig task

Tags: join, foreach, apache-pig

I have been trying pig for a few days and I am not getting the hang of it. I am trying to do simple practice tasks but to no avail. The goal is to create a record which shows the max runs for each ID per year. So I started off with:

`A = LOAD 'pig/input/Batting.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (ID:int, year:int, stint:chararray, team:chararray, league:chararray, games:int, games_bat:int, atbat:int, runs:int);
B = GROUP A by year;
C = FOREACH B generate group, MAX(A.runs) as maxruns;`

I assumed all went well up until this point but then it got totally messed up when:

`D = JOIN A by year, C by year;
E = FOREACH D generate group, D.(group, ID), maxruns;
store E into 'batting_result';`

any tips or ideas on which direction to go to would be much appreciated.

Comment: What output did you expect? What did you get?  Were there any errors?

Comment: I adjusted it a little and I think I got a bit further. So far it looks like this

`A = LOAD 'pig/input/Batting.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (ID:int, year:int, stint:chararray, team:chararray, league:chararray, games:int, games_bat:int, atbat:int, runs:int);  
B = GROUP A by year;  
C = FOREACH B generate group, MAX(A.runs) AS maxruns:int;
D = JOIN A by runs, C by maxruns;
E = FOREACH D generate group, ID, maxruns;
dump E;`

As an output I get 
(1893,,149)
(1893,,149)
etc.

However, that middle space needs to show the ID for the corresponding "maxruns", instead it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a similar [dataset](http://seanlahman.com/files/database/lahman591-csv.zip), one issue might be that the first column(playerId) from the csv file is a chararrray not an int.

I think there might be something wrong with your join (in the pig query written in your comment).

Relation C, has two columns group/year and maxruns.
To get the playerId from A, we have to join on year and runs.
So, your relation D should look like

```
D = JOIN A by (year,runs), C by (group,maxruns);
```

With that change, you should get for every year, the max runs of that year, and the player id of the player.

Hope that helped